# Derivation of following Fourier Transform (found in a table)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Formula 20 on page 9 of [this text](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf) has that for

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^4 + 2a^2x^2\cos(2\theta)+a^4}\qquad a>0, \quad|\theta|<\frac{\pi}{2},$$
we have
$$\hat f(y) = \frac{\pi}{2a^3}e^{-a y \cos\theta}\sin(\theta+a y \sin\theta)\csc(2\theta)$$

where

$$\hat f(y) \equiv \int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(yx)dx,\qquad y>0$$

is the Fourier transform for even functions $f(x)$. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g(z)=z^4+2a^2\cos(2\theta)z^2+a^4$ has zeroes for the four values of $z$ such that

$$z=\pm ia e^{\ i\theta}, \pm iae^{-i\theta}$$

For $a>0$, the zeroes of $g(z)$ that are in the upper-half plane are at $iae^{\pm i\theta}$.  Hence, the residue theorem in conjunction with Jordan's Lemma guarantee that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iyx}}{x^4+2a^2\cos(2\theta)x^2+a^4}\,dx&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iyz}}{z^4+2a^2\cos(2\theta)z^2+a^4}, z=ia e^{\pm i\theta}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{e^{-aye^{i\theta}}}{-4ia^3e^{i3\theta}+i2a^3e^{i\theta}\cos(2\theta)}+\frac{e^{-aye^{-i\theta}}}{-4ia^3e^{-i3\theta}+i2a^3e^{-i\theta}\cos(2\theta)}\right)\\\\
&=(\pi/2a^3)\left(i\csc(2\theta)e^{-(i\theta+ a y e^{i\theta})}-i\csc(2\theta)e^{(i\theta-a y e^{-i\theta})}\right)\\\\ 
&=-\frac{\pi \csc(2\theta)}{a^3} \text{Im}\left(e^{-aye^{i\theta}-i\theta}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi\csc(2\theta)}{a^3}e^{-ay\cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta+ay\sin(\theta))
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: After reading on the residue theorem for the last few days I was ready to suggest this idea. Excellent demonstration!

Comment: @markviola Thank you! Could you explain how you went between 2nd and 3rd steps?

Comment: @dwagg You're welcome.  My pleasure.  In going from the second to third step, I used Euler's formula to simplify the denominator.

Comment: In Fourier analysis we use the Fourier inversion theorem to find the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x - ia}$, not the residue theorem.